# What is a fast way to compute column by column correlation in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

I have two very large matrices (60x25000) and I'd like to compute the correlation between the columns only between the two matrices. For example:

```
corrVal(1) = corr(mat1(:,1), mat2(:,1);
corrVal(2) = corr(mat1(:,2), mat2(:,2);
...
corrVal(i) = corr(mat1(:,i), mat2(:,i);
```

For smaller matrices I can simply use:

```
   colCorr = diag( corr( mat1, mat2 ) );
```

but this doesn't work for very large matrices as I run out of memory. I've considered slicing up the matrices to compute the correlations and then combining the results but it seems like a waste to compute correlation between column combinations that I'm not actually interested.

Is there a quick way to directly compute what I'm interested?

**Edit**: I've used a loop in the past but its just way to slow:

```
mat1 = rand(60,5000);
mat2 = rand(60,5000);
nCol = size(mat1,2);
corrVal = zeros(nCol,1);

tic;
for i = 1:nCol
    corrVal(i) = corr(mat1(:,i), mat2(:,i));
end
toc;
```

This takes ~1 second

```
tic;
corrVal = diag(corr(mat1,mat2));
toc;
```

This takes ~0.2 seconds

Comment: I made an edit to your post ; please check if it's correct.

Comment: Also, what's wrong  with the obvious for loop?

Comment: the edit is correct, thanks! Also the loop is way to slow

Comment: I made another change. Also, on my PC, the loop took ~1.7s and the `diag` version is still running (well over a minute).

Comment: OK, I reduced the matrix to 60x500 and the loop & diag versions took ~0.17s and ~16.7s resp.

Comment: hmm... thats interesting, what version of matlab are you running and how many cores do you have? I'm running 2011b and have 8 cores which might be giving diag the edge on my machine. When diag executes I see activity spike on most of my cores.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can obtain a **x100** speed improvement by computing it by hand.

```
An=bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A,1)); %%% zero-mean
Bn=bsxfun(@minus,B,mean(B,1)); %%% zero-mean
An=bsxfun(@times,An,1./sqrt(sum(An.^2,1))); %% L2-normalization
Bn=bsxfun(@times,Bn,1./sqrt(sum(Bn.^2,1))); %% L2-normalization
C=sum(An.*Bn,1); %% correlation
```

You can compare using that code:

```
A=rand(60,25000);
B=rand(60,25000);

tic;
C=zeros(1,size(A,2));
for i = 1:size(A,2)
    C(i)=corr(A(:,i), B(:,i));
end
toc; 

tic
An=bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A,1));
Bn=bsxfun(@minus,B,mean(B,1));
An=bsxfun(@times,An,1./sqrt(sum(An.^2,1)));
Bn=bsxfun(@times,Bn,1./sqrt(sum(Bn.^2,1)));
C2=sum(An.*Bn,1);
toc
mean(abs(C-C2)) %% difference between methods
```

Here are the computing times:

```
Elapsed time is 10.822766 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.119731 seconds.
```

The difference between the two results is very small:

```
mean(abs(C-C2))

ans =
  3.0968e-17
```

**EDIT: explanation**

`bsxfun` does a column-by-column operation (or row-by-row depending on the input).

```
An=bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A,1));
```

This line will remove (`@minus`) the mean of each column (`mean(A,1)`) to each column of `A`... So basically it makes the columns of `A` zero-mean.

```
An=bsxfun(@times,An,1./sqrt(sum(An.^2,1)));
```

This line multiply (@times) each column by the inverse of its norm. So it makes them L-2 normalized.

Once the columns are zero-mean and L2-normalized, to compute the correlation, you just have to make the dot product of each column of `An` with each column of `B`. So you multiply them element-wise `An.*Bn`, and then you sum each column: `sum(An.*Bn);`.

Comment: wow that is fast. Can you give me a quick explanation as to why this works?

Comment: Thank youuuuuu for the great answer @Oli

Answer (score 1):

I think the obvious loop might be good enough for your size of problem. On my laptop it takes less than 6 seconds to do the following:

```
A = rand(60,25000);
B = rand(60,25000);
n = size(A,1);
m = size(A,2);

corrVal = zeros(1,m);
for k=1:m
    corrVal(k) = corr(A(:,k),B(:,k));
end
```

Comment: Wait, what am I missing?  diag(corr(A,B)); takes over 10 seconds for me.

Comment: Can you run `diag(corr(A,B))` on matrices that big? I get an out of memory error when I try to run in on these matrices

Comment: @slayton: I don't think you can. Besides, it seems that the loop version is faster!

Comment: @slayton I have 8GB of RAM, and it fills about 5GB of it, but it works.